# Removing a redundant variable/shortening code

Tags: java

I need to remove the "min" variable and still allow the sorting program to run however, I am confused on where exactly to start.

```
    int[] A = {13, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, 21, 1, 8};


    for (int k=0; k<A.length-1; k++) {

        int min = A[k];
        int minPosition = k;

        for (int i=k+1; i<A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] < min) {
                min = A[i];
                minPosition = i;
            }
        }
        int temp = A[k];
        A[k] = A[minPosition];
        A[minPosition] = temp;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        System.out.println (A[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both `min` and `minPosition`:

```
int min = A[k];
int minPosition = k;
```

Start by removing the declaration for `min` altogether (delete the line `int min = A[k]`), delete the line `min = A[i]`, and finally, edit the `if` statement from this:

```
if (A[i] < min) {
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
if (A[i] < A[minPosition]) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 variables that are doing the same job :

i) **min** which keeps track of the minimum in the array

ii) **minPosition** which is index of the **min** value.

You can simply compare everytime with the element at minPosition and swap it in the end.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[] A = { 13, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, 21, 1, 8 };

        for (int k = 0; k < A.length - 1; k++) {

            // int min = A[k];
            int minPosition = k;

            for (int i = k + 1; i < A.length; i++) {
                if (A[i] < A[minPosition]) {

                    minPosition = i;
                }
            }
            int temp = A[k];
            A[k] = A[minPosition];
            A[minPosition] = temp;
        }

        // for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
        // }
    }
}
```